# printing user input multiple times with different instances in ruby

Tags: ruby

is there a way to make this script run with just one puts? Where the user input would be what the puts statement prints out?

```
  print "Which harmonic sums do you wish to calculate? "
          sum = gets.to_i

  def harmonic_sum(n)
        (1..n).inject(Fraction.new(0,1)) {|r, i| r + Fraction.new(1,i) }
  end    

  puts  harmonic_sum(1)
  puts  harmonic_sum(2)
  puts  harmonic_sum(3)
  puts  harmonic_sum(4)
  puts  harmonic_sum(5)
```

Would I have to make a local variable in order to run this as a loop and if so what kind of loop would I run. I've see other posts saying a while loop or for loop would work, but which one would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  1.upto(sum) do |n|
    harmonic_sum(n)
  end
```

Comment: Make sure `puts harmonic_sum(n)` instead of just calling it!